# mod_rewrite all and if not found

Tags: apache-httpd, mod-rewrite

I need to make some rewrite rules, but I doesn't use Apache HTTP for years and little bit confused with rules...

Task:

1. rewrite URLs from `http://example.com/test/file.js` to `http://example.com/test/1/file.js`
2. if file `http://example.com/test/1/file.js` is NOT found - return file `http://example.com/test/1/index.html` instead;

I suppose - it must looks like this:

```
    <Location /test>
            AllowOverride All

            # if file http://example.com/test/1/file.js found - return it
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/1/$1 [L]

            # if file http://example.com/test/1/file.js NOT found - return index.html form /1/ subdir
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/1/index.html [L]

    </Location>
```

Content of `/test/`:

```
# ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 20 10:14 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 Aug 20 08:57 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3 Aug 20 10:06 jj.ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Aug 20 08:50 test.html
```

And `/test/1/`:

```
# ls -l 1
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15 Aug 20 11:02 file.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13 Aug 20 10:03 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7 Aug 20 10:14 jj.ll
```

But- if I try to open URL like `http://example.com/test/file.js` - I'm getting file `http://example.com/test/1/index.html` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in such way:

```
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/1
            RewriteRule ^.*test(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/1$1 [L]

            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
            RewriteRule ^.*test(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/1/$1 [L]

            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^.*test(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/1/index.html [L]
```

Seems works.